# CSS hover not working, inside a bootstrap modal overlay

Tags: html, css

I am making a modal view, using bootstrap framework, as shown in the figure , these are two buttons , I want hover effect when , mouse points on, using CSS but it isn't working,

```css
#yesbut,#nobut {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 35px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #2e6c96;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #2e6c96;
    outline: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

#yesbut :hover{
  background: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
}
#nobut :hover{
  background: #fff;
    color: #2e6c96;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="yesbut" >YES</div>
<div id="nobut">NO</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjXFR.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got error in selectors corrected is:

```
#yesbut:hover{
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

without space between `#yesbut`/`#yesno` and `:hover`.

Space mean you are targeting elements inside that particular element e.g. children of `#yesbut`.

Comment: my bad !!, thank-you; btw , i didnt knew that, knowing this is will be very helpful. thank-you

Answer (score 6):

```html
#yesbut :hover{               /*Remove the space*/
  background: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the spaces. If you put a space before the pseudo-class it means that you want to select a child of e.g. `#yesbut` instead of the element itself.

```css
#yesbut,#nobut {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 35px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #2e6c96;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #2e6c96;
    outline: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

#yesbut:hover{
  background: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
}
#nobut:hover{
  background: #fff;
    color: #2e6c96;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="yesbut" >YES</div>
<div id="nobut">NO</div>
```